# fixing cpan by resetting it

Tags: centos, perl, cpan

So I ran into a simple little problem.
I wasn't connected to the internet and started cpan. It started to configure for the first time and then when I realised a few seconds later that the internet wasn't connected I hit `Ctrl + C`

When I connected to the internet and brought CPAN up again, it asked me to continue from where is left, but prompted me for a WHOLE lot of configuration options. I left them to default.

It then asked me for a **mirror URL**, I think I typed it incorrectly. Now cpan doesn't work at all!!

I would like to reset to the typical first start I'm used to where it will ask to configure everything for me.

I looked at [this perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=975452) post which suggested deleting `/etc/perl/CPAN/Config.pm` but it doesn't exist for me. `/etc/perl` doesn't exist itself.

**Question**: I'm on CentOS 6.4, how do I reset cpan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe `cpan` maintains its files in the directory of the user that ran it. So if it was root then they'd be in `/root/.cpan`. You can just blow this directory away completely.

Alternatively you can re-run the "wizard" that asks you all those CPAN questions using this command:

```
$ cpan o conf init
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I deleted the directory `/root/.cpan` cpan still doesn't give me that first launch message, when I did `sudo cpan` then `cpan> o conf init` it ran all the regular auto configuration **except** the urllist config, but prompted me to do that. When I did it let me select a continent, country and gave me the right list of mirrors. It's all working now :D

Answer (score 2):

Removing `/root/.cpan` certainly helps, but if you want to go back to the first launch message, you need to remove `CPAN/Config.pm`.  To find out where it is, try:

```
perldoc -l CPAN
```

i.e.:

```
ls -l `dirname $(perldoc -l CPAN)`/CPAN/Config.pm
```

Answer (score 1):

replace Config.pm with fixed version

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-2.16.tar.gz
tar -zxvf CPAN-2.16.tar.gz
sudo mkdir  /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/ -p
sudo cp ./CPAN-2.16/lib/CPAN/FirstTime.pm /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FirstTime.pm
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/broxio/15d1a4a9f1567f70cfe675d2ff226118)

Answer (score 0):

On my shared hosting server, there is also a ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm file. Deleting the whole `~/.cpan` folder did the job for me. Deleting `/usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Config.pm` requires root privilege so no can do for me.

This code works for me to reset and re-run cpan setup with no output (extracted from my sslcert cron script).

```
if [ -d ~/.cpan ]; then rm -fR ~/.cpan ; echo y | cpan > /dev/null 2>&1; fi
```

Same line also ran on my ubuntu desktop pc.

Answer (score -1):

delete `/usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Config.pm` and then run CPAN again